# DSolve[] is unable to compute the symbolic solution of a non-linear BVP with double Neumann BCs

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, symbolic, nonlinear

I am looking for a symbolic closed-form solution to the following BVP.

$$\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x}\phi(x) =  k j(x)$$

where $k$ is a real-valued scalar constant, and  $j(x)$ is a strongly non-linear function given by $$j(x) = j_0 (e^{\frac{(1-\alpha)F \eta(x)}{RT}} - e^{\frac{-\alpha F \eta(x)}{RT}})$$

wherein, $j_0$, $\alpha$, $R$ & $T$ are scalar constants, and

$$\eta(x) = \phi(x) - a - b$$

where $a$ and $b$ are two other constants.

The boundary conditions are $\phi'(0) = 0$ & $\phi'(1) = 1$ in the unit domain $(0,1)$

I tried solving this using DSolve, but was unsuccessful.  Then, I tried solving for a linearised version of $j(x)$ using a Taylor expansion about an operating point $\phi^*$. This code works and produces a symbolic answer. I do realise that non-linear problems are hard, and do not have a general solution. But in this case, I do know that we have a solution (from theory, and also was able to compute it numerically with a relative error/tolerance of $10^{-7}$).

Furthermore, even though we have a double Neumann BC for this elliptic problem, we have a unique solution due to the fact that the source term is implicit, i.e. it contains the field variable $\phi(x)$ being solved for.

Any help regarding solving this problem in Mathematica is highly appreciated. The code I tried for the linearised version is given below

```
Eta =  Phi[x] - a - b
linearisedBV = Collect[Normal[Series[(Exp[((1 - alpha) F Eta)/(R T)] -  Exp[ (-alpha F Eta)/(R T)]), {Phi[x], phistar, 1}]], Phi[x]]
eqn = Phi''[x] == k*j0*linearisedBV
soln = DSolve[{eqn, Phi'[0] == 0, Phi'[1] == 1}, Phi[x], x]
```

Comment: `soln = DSolve[{eqn, Phi[0] == 0, Phi'[1] == 1}, Phi[x], x]` also, you're missing a curly bracket before `Phi[x]` in `linearisedBV`

Comment: Yup.Sorry, I have the correct syntax in my mathematica file and it runs fine. They are just typos that crept in when I copied and pasted onto this forum. The typos in the code are now fixed.

Comment: The last line of the linearized calculation should contain `Phi'[0] == 0` instead of `Phi[0] == 0`.

Answer (score 4):

The nonlinear problem in the question,

```
Eta =  Phi[x] - a - b;
eqn = Phi''[x] == k*j0*(Exp[((1 - alpha) F Eta)/(R T)] -  Exp[ (-alpha F Eta)/(R T)]);
soln = DSolve[{eqn, Phi'[0] == 0, Phi'[1] == 1}, Phi[x], x]
```

yields an empty solution set with the explanatory warning

> > DSolve::bvimp: General solution contains implicit solutions. In the boundary value problem, these solutions will be ignored, so some of the solutions will be lost.

`DSolve`, or more precisely `Solve`, which it calls, cannot invert the boundary conditions.  Sometimes,

```
SetOptions[Solve, Method -> Reduce]
```

overcomes this difficulty, but not here.  Instead, apply `DSolve` without boundary conditions, which yields,

```
s = soln = DSolve[eqn, Phi[x], x]

(* Solve[
     Integrate[1/Sqrt[(2*E^((F*(a*(-1 + alpha) + (-1 + alpha)*b - alpha*K[1]))/(R*T))*
     ((-1 + alpha)*E^(((a + b)*F)/(R*T)) - alpha*E^((F*K[1])/(R*T)))*j0*k*R*T)/
     ((-1 + alpha)*alpha*F) + C[1]], {K[1], 1, Phi[x]}]^2 == (x + C[2])^2, Phi[x]] *)
```

That neither `Solve` nor `Reduce` can make headway with this equation is, perhaps, not surprising.  Nonetheless, some progress can be made.  First, extract the equation from within `s` and take the square root of both sides.

```
ss = s[[1]] /. Power[z_, 2] -> z

(* Integrate[1/Sqrt[(2*E^((F*(a*(-1 + alpha) + (-1 + alpha)*b - alpha*K[1]))/(R*T))*
   ((-1 + alpha)*E^(((a + b)*F)/(R*T)) - alpha*E^((F*K[1])/(R*T)))*j0*k*R*T)/
   ((-1 + alpha)*alpha*F) + C[1]], {K[1], 1, Phi[x]}] == x + C[2] *)
```

(*Edit:* The following was rewritten to properly address boundary conditions.)
The boundary conditions now can be applied to determine the constant `C[1]` as follows.  To obtain `Phi'[x]`, differentiate `ss`, multiply the resulting equation by the denominator of the left side of the equation, and square both sides.

```
sss = (Numerator[D[ss, x][[1]]])^2 == (Denominator[D[ss, x][[1]]])^2

(* Derivative[1][Phi][x]^2 == 
   (2*E^((F*(a*(-1 + alpha) + (-1 + alpha)*b - alpha*Phi[x]))/(R*T))*
   ((-1 + alpha)*E^(((a + b)*F)/(R*T)) - alpha*E^((F*Phi[x])/(R*T)))*j0*k*R*T)/
   ((-1 + alpha)*alpha*F) + C[1 *)
```

Note that this result also can be obtained by multiplying `eqn` by `Phi'[x]` and integrating.  Now `C[1]` can be computed trivially by

```
First@Solve[sss /. x -> 0 /. Phi'[0] -> 0, C[1]]

(* {C[1] -> (-2*E^((F*(a*(-1 + alpha) + (-1 + alpha)*b - alpha*Phi[0]))/(R*T))*
    (-E^(((a + b)*F)/(R*T)) + alpha*E^(((a + b)*F)/(R*T)) - alpha*E^((F*Phi[0])/(R*T)))*j0*
    k*R*T)/((-1 + alpha)*alpha*F)} *)
```

as well as from `First@Solve[sss /. x -> 1 /. Phi'[1] -> 1, C[1]]`.  Consistency of these two results requires

```
1 == (sss[[2]] /. x -> 1) - (sss[[2]] /. x -> 0)

(* 1 == (-2*E^((F*(a*(-1 + alpha) + (-1 + alpha)*b - alpha*Phi[0]))/(R*T))*
   ((-1 + alpha)*E^(((a + b)*F)/(R*T)) - alpha*E^((F*Phi[0])/(R*T)))*j0*k*R*T)/
   ((-1 + alpha)*alpha*F) + 
   (2*E^((F*(a*(-1 + alpha) + (-1 + alpha)*b - alpha*Phi[1]))/(R*T))*
   ((-1 + alpha)*E^(((a + b)*F)/(R*T)) - alpha*E^((F*Phi[1])/(R*T)))*j0*k*R*T)/
   ((-1 + alpha)*alpha*F) *)
```

A solution to the nonlinear ODE `eqn` therefore exists only if this consistency condition can be satisfied.  Adjusting `C[2]` may well be sufficient to satisfy the consistency condition, but determining the necessary value for `C[2]` appears to be a numerical calculation.

**Addendum**

A little more progress can be made for the special case, `alpha == 1/2`.

```
eqn = Phi''[x] == 2 k*j0*Sinh[Eta F/(2 R T)];
soln = Phi[x] /. DSolve[{eqn}, Phi[x], x] /. 
    JacobiAmplitude[z1_, z2_] :> JacobiAmplitude[Simplify[z1], z2]

(* {(a F + b F + 4 I R T JacobiAmplitude[(I Sqrt[F] Sqrt[8 j0 k R T + F C[1]] (x + C[2]))/
       (4 R T), (16 j0 k R T)/(8 j0 k R T + F C[1])])/F, 
    {(a F + b F - 4 I R T JacobiAmplitude[(I Sqrt[F] Sqrt[8 j0 k R T + F C[1]] (x + C[2]))/
       (4 R T), (16 j0 k R T)/(8 j0 k R T + F C[1])])/F} *)
```

Unfortunately, the resulting boundary conditions cannot be solved symbolically by Mathematica for the two constants of integration.

```
Solve[{0 == D[soln[[1]], x] /. x -> 0, 1 == D[soln[[1]], x] /. x -> 1}, {C[1], C[2]}]
```

returns unevaluated with the message

> > Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.

`Reduce` does no better.

**Second Addendum**

The OP indicates in a comment below that only `Phi[0]` is needed.  I know of no way to obtain even that symbolically.  However, it can be obtained numerically without difficulty.  For instance, with `a + b == 0`, `k j0 == 1`, and `F/(R T) == 1`,

```
eqn = Phi''[x] == Exp[(1 - alpha) Phi[x]] - Exp[ -alpha Phi[x]];
ParametricNDSolveValue[{eqn, Phi'[0] == 0, Phi'[1] == 1}, Phi[0], x, {alpha}];
Plot[%[alpha], {alpha, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {alpha, "Phi[0]"}]
```

[image]

Comment: I have understood your derivation and code thus far, including the calculation of C[1] and the corresponding consistency condition. However, I am still unable to understand how one might proceed further with this calculation. How do we link this back to C[2] (as per the last sentence of your post) ? If it will help any further, I am **NOT** interested in solution over the entire domain. All that I need is the value of Phi[0].  What are the potential next steps you'd recommend to solve this problem ?

Comment: @Krishna  I believe that progress can be made only if numerical values are assigned to the three constants `alpha`, `a + b`, and `F/(R T)`.